# Finding sentiment analysis for all the rows in the dataframe and not just one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I am unable to get sentiment for all the rows in the dataframe. Able to see sentiment for only one row.

Comment: It makes things easier if you post the actual code, not just images of it.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I am unable to copy paste the code perfectly. It is mixing up all lines of code into a paragraph. Kindly help me with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text = doc.text[0]`

This statement only brings 1st row. Hence, you see only 1st row in your answerset.

For getting sentiments for all rows, run a loop:

```
for index, row in doc.iterrows():
    text = row[0]
    obj = TextBlob(text)
    sentiment = obj.sentiment.polarity
    print(sentiment)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Mayank, thank you for the reply. This is the error which I got TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Try it again.

Comment: Thank you Mayank, it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great, If the answer helped you, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grey to fill in. Thanks.